# css classes not working

Tags: css, class, hover, toggle

I have a bunch of divs that I've set up, and I was trying to swap classes on a child div when you hover over the parent. Right now I'm trying to do it with jQuery, but I would also be happy to use pseudo classes.

The hover doesn't work and I think it's because the style was listed as inline, but when I remove the style from inline and do it as a class the entire div just disappears.  It's suppose to be a 3d stack, and so it's just a div with a white background and an opacity set.

---

The div is:

```
<div id = "3dstack_4" class = "3dstack_4_nohover"></div>
```

...and I have the class listed as:

```
.3dstack_4_nohover {
    border:0px solid red;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(1px, 14px, 0px);
    position:absolute;
    z-index:12;
    height:34px;
    width:46px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    opacity:.3;
}
```

---

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7EH7X/4/. Thanks for any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

I would do that using CSS. Here is a very simple example:

The HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
</div>​
```

The CSS

```
#container > div {
    display: none
}
#container > div:first-child {
    display: block
}
#container:hover > div {
    display: block
}​
```

Then add the other details as you progress. Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4p8CM/3/)

Good luck.

Comment: so I tried to update what you did to fit what I'm doing, the child div doesn't show, can you just take a quick look: http://jsfiddle.net/4p8CM/220/

Comment: Perhaps if you rephrase your question once more, what exactly are you trying to achieve? I might have misunderstood it.